# Stopping modal when window is closed (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, modal-dialog, nswindow

I am currently displaying a modal window by using this code:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:mainWindow];
```

However, when I close this window, the other windows are still inactive. How do I run the `stopModal` method when the window is closed using the "red x"?

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a delegate for the window and have it respond to either the
**-(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification** or the
**- (void)windowShouldClose:(NSNotification *)notification** methods like so:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
   [[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModal];
}
```

See [Mac Dev Center: NSWindowDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSWindowDelegate)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dialog that applies to a specific window, then you probably shouldn't be using a modal dialog but a sheet. Modal dialogs should be avoided if possible. If you use a sheet then the problem that you're experiencing will no longer be an issue.

```
- (void)showSheet:(id)sender
{
    [NSApp beginSheet:yourModalWindow 
        modalForWindow:windowThatSheetIsAttachedTo
        modalDelegate:self
        didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
           contextInfo:nil];
}

- (void)sheetDidEnd:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [sheet orderOut:self];
    [NSApp endSheet:sheet];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with *Randall's* answer you can link the controller class as the delegate for the window defined in your .xib file.

You can handle the

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModal];
```

in either

- `-(void)performClose:(id)sender`
- `-(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification`

methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 (note that the previous methods are deprecated):**

```
window.beginSheet(self.uiSettingsPanel, completionHandler: {response in
        NSLog("Finished sheet, response: \(response)")
})
```

where self.uiSettingsPanel is the instance of the NSPanel subclass. Then, within the NSPanel sub-class for the sheet, close it with something like

```
@IBAction func buttonOK(_ sender: NSButton) {
    self.sheetParent!.endSheet(self, returnCode: .OK)
}
```